# Boolean logic in Future[Boolean]

Tags: scala, future, boolean-logic

In non-concurrent programming, we usually have this kind of boolean logic:

```
boolean canIMarryher(){
    return iLoveHer() && myParentsLoveHer() && shesHot() && sheSaidYes();
}
```

Here comes my question, what if all these(or some of these conditions) are Future[Boolean] in scala? Can I still get a clear method just like the example above?

**Update**
As you know, in boolean logic at run time we'll have 'optimization' like: immediately return when using `&&` and met a `false` or using `||` and met a `true`. Can I have it in Future[Boolean] as well?

Regards,
Drew

Comment: Firstly the above is not valid Scala code (not sure if you intended it to be pseudo-code). Also `Future[Boolean]` is a different type to just `Boolean` so you would not be able to simply combine the logic as above if some of the expressions are of mixed type. Also Future[Boolean] are composed using combinators not boolean operators.

Comment: Yeah it is just a piece of pseudo-code of course.  And I don't care whether I get a Future[Boolean] or a Boolean, just a method does the same thing with Future[Boolean]. Maybe I should put it like this, how can I apply boolean operator on Future[Boolean]?

Comment: Apply boolean operator to a `Future`? It doesn't make sense to do that. I think you are confused about what a Future is. You can apply it to a future value though.

Comment: I know it is not possible to simply apply those operators on a Future. But my case it's solid when comes to a validation method with a bunch of Future[Boolean] to rely on. I just want to know what's the best pattern of it in Scala.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answers with for-comprehension and reduce will not "short-circuit." That is, if the first future takes a while to complete, we will wait that whole time even if the second future evaluates `false` immediately.

To clarify, this is different from short-circuiting in traditional boolean logic where we evaluate the right-hand side of the operator by-name. Instead, the goal is to produce the answer as fast as possible. We start every future's computation immediately, and short-circuit if possible as the results come in. In the best case, we only have to wait for the fastest future, and in the worst case, we have to wait for the slowest future.

Here's a method which supports this type of short-circuiting:

```
def all(futures: Future[Boolean]*)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[Boolean] = {
  Future.find(futures) { !_ } map { _.isEmpty }
}

def canIMarryher = all(iLoveHer, myParentsLoveHer, shesHot, sheSaidYes)
```

If you really wanted to, you could take the idea further and define && and || methods for `Future[Boolean]`

Comment: Hey, that's a cool idea, Implementing that in my future-juggling library "futiles" right away. The boolean algebra combinators, I mean.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/johanandren/futiles/blob/master/src/main/scala/markatta/futiles/Boolean.scala#L8

Comment: @johanandren I added some clarification to my answer. I think it's most desirable to minimize the time waiting for the future to complete. Consider this case: `Future { Thread.sleep(1000); true } && Future.successful(false)`

Comment: Ouch, didn't think of that. But, it could essentially be completed as soon as one completes with false or true, depending on operation. Good point.

Comment: Using `Future.firstCompletedOf` and a small library from @johanandren comment it should be easy to implement this shortcircuit semantics.

Answer (score 5):

As math said, `Future.reduce` is good if you can see them as a sequence of values, if you need to stick more meaning to each of them you can use a for comprehension:

```
val isThereAFuture: Future[Boolean] = 
  for {
    iLoveHer <- doILoveHer()
    myParentsLoveHer <- doMyParentsLoveHer()
    sheLovesMe <- doesSheLoveMe()
  } yield iLoveHer && myParentsLoveHer && sheLovesMe
```

Comment: I think it is the best solution so far. However can I make a further question? In my pseudo code, the code stop running down after first `false` was encountered. I think `for comprehension` cannot have this kind of "optimization", right?

Comment: That is true, you could achieve something like it using guards in the for comprehension (`iLoveHer <- doILoveHer() if iLoveHer`) however that would be less clean, and would trigger an exception for `false`, which you would then have to `recover` to `false`.